# How to align my buttons to the right and center the header?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I used the following code to output the interface as shown below.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card m-b-30">
        <div class="card-header container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="card-title">Customer Profile Types</h2>
                <div class="col-md-4 float-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em">Update</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <br>
        <div class="CustomerProfileTypes-body">

            <form>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputText">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
                        <label id="gridCheck"> Active</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

But I need to get the output as shown below and align all the things in my interface.

The name also needs to be centered and textbox, and the checkbox also should be aligned.

I'm still a beginner can anyone help me.

[image]

Comment: Provide your CSS code in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be two solutions for the result you are trying to achieve.

1. Make use of bootstrap columns like you are using right now.
2. Use flexbox

**Solution 1**
Make a slight change to your code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6>
    <h2 class="card-title">Customer Profile Types</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em">Update</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2**
Without the bootstrap row and col, pure flexbox (using bootstrap classes).

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <h2 class="card-title">Customer Profile Types</h2>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em">Update</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CSS, try to use **flexbox** with property "**space-between**" on this div (because is father):

```
<div class="card-header container-fluid">
```

It should make space between h2 and B's elements.

Comment: Or try to divide that div into two divs "div for h2" and "div for B's", then, using bootstrap class="float-right or left, maybe it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="padding: 10px">
<div class="card m-b-30">
    <div class="card-header container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="card-title" style="padding: 10px">Customer Profile Types</h2>
            <div align="right" class="col-md-8 float-right">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em">Update</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <br>
    <div class="CustomerProfileTypes-body">

        <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" style="text-align: center"> Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputText">

                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" style="margin-left: 2px" >

                    <label id="gridCheck" style="margin-left: 15px"> Active </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```